# Absolute Location of a Mesh with Curve Modifier Applied

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, transforms, animation-nodes

I animated a plane moving continuously in the y axis. It has a curve modifier applied, and follows the curving path. A change in the planes x location is not reflected in the plane's object properties. I would like to use the *perceived* change in x location as an object input for animation nodes. Is there any way to see what the "absolute" location of the mesh is, where I am actually seeing it in space in object mode?

[image]

Comment: Many experienced Blender Users may temporarily feel such a need which is replaced by a solution to the higher level needs.  What is your higher level need?

Comment: What do you really want to do with this information? .......... The UI displays location before it is affected by other modifiers. It is unlikely you will be able to easily change the standard UI and probably unwise. If you program in Python you may be able to display the final location of any element either in the [new] UI element or the text console, or a file such as an export. Most people do not feel a [permanent] need to change this established display of Blender. I doubt you feel the need just out of curiosity. What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: The modifiers and constraints and other features of Blender should reduce your need to feel the standard display should be changed.

Comment: I would like the perceived viewport location to drive transforms on another object, like scale. So as I perceive that is moving in the x-direction, object 2's y scale is changed. The ultimate goal is to animate objects which respond to the curve in a dynamic way. The undulation of the curve drives other transforms to create a nice effect. I could do it by hand but the goal is to do is procedurally with svercock and animation nodes.

Comment: I might look into using the wave modifier to create the desired effect. While the amplitude of the curves can not be drawn with the curve tool, it can be controlled and animated to create a similar effect. Additionally it could generate the curving movement infinitely and randomly.

Comment: The **global** location of an object is `ob.matrix_world.translation`.

Comment: What I should have also requested is that the answers to my comments go into your original question.

Comment: Many of the modifiers operate in such as way that the final location of an object is used.  Have you experienced a problem or are you predicting a problem?  Are you experienced in Python or BAN Blender Animation Nodes?  Again your answers should go into the original question.

Comment: Did you mean to write Sverchok ?

Comment: You used the word [seeing] ... did you mean use the world location as part of a calculation? or did you mean see a value in the UI?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123930/output-ob-matrix-world-translation-as-a-vector-in-animation-nodes.  If you have abandoned this question you can delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Animation Nodes, try to minimize your use of modifiers and constraints, because transferring data between blender and AN is not optimal. In this case, a simple spline evaluation or spline projection will give you what you want:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: What is that AN with 2.8?

Comment: @JorgeLosillaMartínez Yes. Porting started a while ago. It is practically finished now. As far as I know, particle system nodes are the only part that doesn't work yet. There is a bug report in the tracker, so as soon as it gets attention, we will implement a fix in AN and it will be ready.

Comment: That is more than great news!!!