# Output ob.matrix_world.translation as a Vector in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I would like to make a script which will allow me to output the ob.matrix_world.translation value of an object as I would a normal vector. The ob.matrix_world.translation will be plugged into an Object Transforms Input node.

Comment: Similar question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123924/absolute-location-of-a-mesh-with-curve-modifier-applied

Comment: Not a big user of animation nodes but suspect the world output from [Object matrix nnode](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/object/matrix_input.html) might be it.  Feel free to ask via [comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123924/absolute-location-of-a-mesh-with-curve-modifier-applied#comment216297_123924)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Object Attribute Input* node to get any attribute of an object:

[image: Node Tree]

In this case, the *Object Matrix Input* node can be used. You can decompose the output matrix to get the required vector.